# Show that $\phi$ induces a canonical homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Can someone give me a hint on how to solve the following question from the textbook Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications by Thomas W. Judson?

[image]

Do I just need to show that $\bar{\phi}$ is a homomorphism using properties from $\phi$?

Comment: Well, you have to define $\overline \phi$ first.  Then show it has the usual properties.

Comment: @lulu I defined $\bar{\phi}$ as $\bar{\phi}(g_{1}H_{1})=\phi(g_{1})H_{2}$. Is this okay?

Comment: @numericalorange Looks good. Now prove it's a well-defined homomorphism

Comment: That makes sense but you still have to prove it is well defined.  Suppose I choose a different representative of the coset?  Why doesn't that change the function?  Hint:  you better use the assumption $\phi (H_1)\subset H_2$ somewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I know how to show it is a homomorphism! Because if $g_{1}H_{1}=g_{1}'H_{1}$, there is an $h_{1}\in H_{1}$ such that $g_{1}=g_{1}'h_{1}$, which shows $\bar{\phi}$ is well-defined by since $\phi(h_{1})\in H_{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a commutative diagram  $$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}G_1 @>\phi>>G_2\\ @VVV@VVV\\ G_1/H_1@>\bar\phi>>G_2/H_2 \end{CD} $$, where the downward arrows are the canonical projections onto the quotients.

So $\bar\phi(gH_1)=\phi(g)H_2$.